# Publishing an swf to Facebook wall - how to pass custom param?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I would like to post a flash item to my wall from my iPhone app.
The swf is displayed on my wall, but unfortunalty I didn't found how to pass it a custom variable, like songUrl.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can pass parameters to your SWF which is embedded in a Facebook Wall post is to embed values in the parameter of your SWF.

Assuming you're using Facebook Connect to publish to the Wall, the URL to your SWF must include any custom variables you'd like to pass to it, e.g.

```
http://...myflashfile.swf?myvar1=foo&myvar2=bar
```

Now in your Actionscript code (assuming you've got a Flex project), you'll do

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.myvar1
```

to get the value of myvar1.

References:

- http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashQueryString/ (for Flash)
- http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashQueryString/indexAs3.html (for Actionscript/Flex)