# Passing parameters to swf without ExternalInterface

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flash

I'm using a simple audio player in Flex 3 that plays a given mp3 from a given url.

My swf is intended to be embeded in Facebook walls.

```
<meta property="og:video" 
      content="http://url/of/my/Player.swf?file=url_of_my_file" />
```

The player works fine, as I'm getting my parameters from the url:

```
http://url/of/my/Player.swf?file=url_of_my_file
```

using

```
var _queryStringFromUrl:String = 
              ExternalInterface.call("window.location.search.substring", 1);
```

My problem is that when the swf is embedded in the facebook wall, the `ExternalInterface` is disabled, so I can't get my url variables.

- Is there an alternative for getting a parameter inside my swf player?
- How does youtue handle that in the following url?

  ```
  <meta property="og:video" 
    content="http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
  ```

Please note that the swf is **not embedded in a html page**.

---

EDIT:

It seems that youtube compiles a new `swf` for every video, with the parameters inside.  Can someone confirm?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use [flashvars](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) for this problem? It initialized and passed on swf init. Parse URL-params by JS and add them to flashvars.

Comment: thank you for the answer but as stated in my question there's no html, the swf is called directly `http://url/of/my/Player.swf?param=val `

Comment: Unfortunately, I don'n know how can you solve this problem in another way... Maybe there are some facebook-specific methods to pass parameters to swf embedded in wall.

Comment: I found answer to similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163269/publishing-an-swf-to-facebook-wall-how-to-pass-custom-param. Author use flashvars and it works as I understand.

Comment: thank you very much. I had to switch to flex 4 to use FlexGlobals as suggested in the other answer (not supported in flex3). My player is now a little bit bigger but I can live with that .. :)